# Ruby on rails script to add new columns in mongo collection with some random data for existed records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I want to write script to insert some random data with new columns for existed collection in mongo using Ruby on rails.

suppose I have Employee collection it has empid name address  with some records,
now I want to add  new column salary for employee collection with all existed employee salary details.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to update each document in the employee collection using the $set operator to set the employee's salary:

http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html#Updating_Documents_with_update